# Media Player with Chapters Support

Tags: music

Is there a MediaPlayer with Chapter Marker support?  I want to listen to audio books and the Economist Audio podcast (> 7 hours/episode).

Comment: I've got a non-android question: Do you subscribe to the Premium Economist Podcast or something?  I get the free Economist podcasts and they are only 10 to 15 minutes long.

Comment: Yes.  The Premium Economist Podcast bundles the audio for the entire "newspaper" edition weekly, word for word, with chapter markers for each article.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used [MortPlayer](http://www.appbrain.com/app/mortplayer-audio-books-%28beta%29/de.stohelit.audiobookplayer) and it supports chapters, multiple bookmarks and remembers your place.  As far as chapters go, it depends on how the audio book is setup, most mp3 audio books save each chapter as a different track and that works just fine.  Also, it's free.

While I haven't tried it, it's my understanding that [Ambling Book Player Pro](http://www.appbrain.com/app/ambling-bookplayer-pro/com.amblingbooks.bookplayerpro) is the cats meow of audio book players, although it costs $9.

I don't really listen to audio books much anymore (too many podcasts to keep up with) and I use [BeyondPod](http://www.appbrain.com/app/beyondpod-podcast-manager/mobi.beyondpod) for my Economist Podcasts.  It remembers the last place you were listening but it doesn't let you set bookmarks.