# Is there a media player which doesn't lose current track when mounting/unmounting the SD card?

Tags: sd-card, media-player, sony-ericsson-xperia-x10

I've got an Xperia X10.

I listen to audio books, so I'd like to keep my position in the playlist.

Whenever I mount the SD card using USB, the standard media player, Mediascape, lose both the playlist and the position.

Do you know of an alternative media player which doesn't have this defect?  (Including paid apps.)

Comment: It's not something I use my phone for, so haven't tried these, but you might have more luck with a media player that's designed with audio book support in mind, such as the ones in this previous question http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1898/media-player-with-chapters-support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mediascape doesn't lose track any more after the latest upgrade of the phone.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is these apps probably store the info on the sdcard, so once you mount it, it is unable to read/write that data.

There is an app that I seen on the market that is supposed to let your phone still access the sdcard even when it is mounted. I do not know if it really works or how well it works, but you might be able to try that.

Answer (score 0):

Stock Music player doesn't lose its spot on all devices. I'm not sure exactly which of my phones I've noticed it properly remember on, but I know that I have seen it. And [Winamp](http://www.winamp.com/android) seems to remember its place as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, well actually I like both music and Audio books and didn’t want to have to drop the book out of the player to play some music.
After a lot of research this App seems the best and so far so good!
*Smart AudioBook Player* [available on Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ak.alizandro.smartaudiobookplayer)

Answer (score -1):

[Meridian Player](http://www.appbrain.com/app/meridian-media-player-autonomy/org.iii.romulus.meridian) has a separate section for Audiobooks - haven't tried out the audiobook functionality, but other features are good enough to make it my music player of choice until Winamp catches up.

I prefer listening to my music in the order that files are listed in separate folders which Winamp doesn't yet support. Also gestures and ID3 tagging, make Meridian a good option.